# How to enable validation for form created in form builder (Symfony2)?

Tags: php, forms, validation, symfony

I create and render my form using form builder but it seems that validation is disabled or work not properly. I keep my validation rules in validation.yml file. Method `$form->isValid()` always return `true`, and `$form->getErrorsAsString()` doesn't show any errors (only `[FieldName1]: No errors, [FieldName2]: No errors ... etc`).

I create form in this way:

```
$form = $this->createForm( new CategoryType(), new Category() );
```

Then I send it to a twig.

What could be the reason? How do I enable validation?

----- *UPDATE* -------------------------

I create a form in this way:

```
public function indexAction()
{
    return $this->render('MyBundle:MyView:index.html.twig', array(
        "form" => $this->createForm( new CategoryType(), new Category() )->createView()
    ));
}
```

CategoryType is very simple:

```
class CategoryType extends AbstractType {
    public function buildForm(FormBuilderInterface $builder, array $options) {

       $builder ->add('name', 'text')
                ->add('categoryId', 'entity', array(
                    'class' => 'MyBundle:Category',
                    'property' => 'name',
                ));
    }

    public function getName() {
        return 'my_form_name';
    }
}
```

And of course validation.yml:

```
MyBundle/Form/Type/CategoryType:
    properties:
    - name:
        - NotBlank: ~
        - Length:
            min: 3
            max: 30

MyBundle/Entity/Category:
    properties:
    - name:
        - NotBlank: ~
        - Length:
            min: 3
            max: 30
```

I do not know exactly which version should I use, but both of them doesn't work.

Comment: are you using annotations to specify constraints? Make sure you: http://symfony.com/doc/current/book/validation.html#validation-and-forms

Comment: do you know what actually function of `$form->isValid()`? Maybe you thinking that this function for checking input validation like javascript in view?

Comment: You should show us where and how you invoke the validators.  Also  how you process the request? Do you invoke $form->handleRequest($request)? There could be a lot of reason why your validation doesn't work. Please more details

Comment: Updated. I added source files.

Answer (score 1):

I think [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12367791/symfony2-how-to-load-validation-yml) topic will help you.

You must check that your validator configuration within config.yml is defined as below:

```
framework:
    validation: { enabled: true, enable_annotations: false }
```

Comment: Still the same problem.

Comment: How do you handle the request ? Since we don't know how you treat the form POST request we can't help you further. In the code you presented us, only the form rendering is shown.