# Symfony 2 problems with validating form

Tags: php, validation, symfony

I want to validate my form. I created validation.yml file in the config folder, my bundle is registered and the file is loaded in DependencyInjection. I get the following error:

```
There is no extension able to load the configuration for "Developer\Forum\ForumBundle\Entity\Registration" (in /var/www/html/forum/src/Developer/Forum/ForumBundle/DependencyInjection/../Resources/config/validation.yml). Looked for namespace "Developer\Forum\ForumBundle\Entity\Registration", found none
```

My validation.yml:

```
Developer\Forum\ForumBundle\Entity\Registration:
    properties:
        name:
            - NotBlank: ~
        surname:
            - NotBlank: ~
```

DependencyInjection:

```
namespace Developer\Forum\ForumBundle\DependencyInjection;

use Symfony\Component\DependencyInjection\ContainerBuilder;
use Symfony\Component\Config\FileLocator;
use Symfony\Component\HttpKernel\DependencyInjection\Extension;
use Symfony\Component\DependencyInjection\Loader;
use Developer\Forum\ForumBundle\Entity\Registration;

/**
 * This is the class that loads and manages your bundle configuration
 *
 * To learn more see {@link http://symfony.com/doc/current/cookbook/bundles/extension.html}
 */
class DeveloperForumForumExtension extends Extension
{
    /**
     * {@inheritdoc}
     */
    public function load(array $configs, ContainerBuilder $container)
    {
        $configuration = new Configuration();
        $config = $this->processConfiguration($configuration, $configs);

        $loader = new Loader\YamlFileLoader($container, new FileLocator(__DIR__.'/../Resources/config'));
        $loader->load('services.yml');
        $loader->load('validation.yml');
    }
}
```

The form itself is working fine, data is saved into the database, but I need some validation. What is missing?

Comment: Try simply to don't load this files in the bundle extension class. So remove the line `$loader->load('validation.yml');`

Comment: Without this, validate doesn't work :(

Comment: check the `config.yml`files the section about `framework:
    ...
    validation:    { enabled: true }`

Answer (score 2):

`/app/Resources/config/validation.yml` is loaded automatically. Don't load it for your configuration, this is wrong.

Add this to your configuration instead, to enable validation and don't let PHP parse annotations.

```
framework:
    validation:
        enabled: true
        enable_annotations: false
```

If you want to add userdefined ymls for validation, you can append it to the parameter `validator.mapping.loader.yaml_files_loader.mapping_files`, ([Symfony2 how to load validation.yml](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12367791/symfony2-how-to-load-validation-yml))